# linking to an html page

Tags: java, html

I want to be able to type in a web address in my java application and view the html behind that web page. I am lost. How do I start?

The main question is how do I link to the html behind a webpage?

Any meta information would help. I haven't done any web stuff before.

---

Thanks guys, thats a huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just interested in the source of the page on a specific URL, you can use the `URL` class and the `openConnection` / `getInputStream` methods:

This sample program prints the content of `http://www.google.com`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
        while (s.hasNextLine())
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The html behind the page you are referring to *is* in all essence the page. When the browser fetches the page it interprets it and renders it in a user friendly way.

When you do it programmatically there is no rendering. Hence the content of the page *is* the html. I would recommend using [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to perform [HTTP requests](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d4e43), or the `URL` method nicely described by @aioobe.

Answer (score 2):

> The main question is how do I link to the html behind a webpage?

There is no difference in linking to a website or the html behind a website. It always points to the HTML source code.

What differs is what is done with it. A webbrowser will interpret and format it and display it to you as a styled website. You can still check its source in your browser though. A Text editor will only display the HTML markup to you.